# Why is -2147483648 automatically promoted to long when it can fit in int?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(-2147483648));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(-2147483647-1));
    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives as output (gcc):

```
8  
4
```

Why is `-2147483648` automatically promoted to `long` in 1<sup>st</sup> `printf` even when it can fit in an `int`?

Also, I tried the same in MinGW and it gives the output:

```
4  
4
```

Can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: MinGW isn't a compiler; I guess you mean gcc built for MinGW .

Comment: It's important to remember that the sizes of `int` and `long` are implementation-defined. `int` must be at least 16 bits wide, `long` must be at least 32 bits wide, and `long` must be at least as wide as `int`. Incidentally, the correct format for printing a `size_t` value is `%zu`.

Comment: The proper way to print values of type `size_t` is with `%zu`, by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The number 2147483648 is too large to fit into an `int`, so it is promoted to `long`.

Then, after the number has already been promoted to `long`, its negative is computed, yielding -2147483648.

If you're curious, you can look at `limits.h`.  On my platform, which uses glibc,

```
#  define INT_MIN       (-INT_MAX - 1)
#  define INT_MAX       2147483647
```

On MinGW, `sizeof(long) == 4`, so promotion to `long` won't cut it.  According to the C11 standard, the value must be promoted to `long long`.  This doesn't happen, probably because your MinGW compiler is defaulting to C90 or earlier.

Comment: OK. So why MinGW does not promote? (In that, long is also same size as int but there is long long with larger size, but it doesn't promote and just prints 4 4)

Comment: @v3ga: `sizeof(long) == 4` on MinGW.

Comment: @DietrichEpp if `sizeof(long) == 4` it cannot hold `2147483648`

Answer (score 7):

`-2147483648` is the integral constant expression `2147483648` with the unary minus operator applied.

Your systems both appear to have `int` and `long` as 32-bit, and `long long` as 64-bit.

Since the base-10 constant `2147483648` cannot fit in `long int`, in C99 it has type `long long int`. However, C90 did not have this type, so in C90 it has type `unsigned long int`.

A common workaround for this issue is, as you say, to write `-2147483647 - 1`. You will probably see something similar as the definition of `INT_MIN` if you check your system's `limits.h` .

Regarding the output `4`, this suggests that on your MinGW system you are using C90 and on your other system you are using C99 or C11 (or C++, or GCC extensions).

Comment: +1 LSNED  C89/90 "The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.  Unsuffixed decimal: `int, long int, unsigned long int`".  C11 `int, long int, long long int`.  With current C, an unsuffixed decimal is never `unsigned anything`.  Not so with earlier C.