# sizeof(2147483648) is 8 bytes while sizeof(2147483647+1) is 4 bytes

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(2147483648));
    printf("%d"  , sizeof(2147483647+1)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
8  
4
```

I understand that `sizeof(2147483648)` is 8 bytes as it cannot fit in 4 bytes and is promoted to `long long int`. But I do not understand what happens in case of `sizeof(2147483647+1)`

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658485/why-is-2147483648-automatically-promoted-to-long-when-it-can-fit-in-int) but it does not discuss the second case.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "int i = 2147483647 + 1;" OK, but "byte b = 127 + 1;" is not compilable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889176/why-is-int-i-2147483647-1-ok-but-byte-b-127-1-is-not-compilable)

Comment: `2147483647+1` is an expression that has two `int` operands so the result is an `int` (and has undefined behavior because of the overflow).  Similarly, `-2147483648` is an expression where the `2147483648` is a `long int` that then has the unary minus operator applied to it,

Comment: Print not only sizes but also the values.

Comment: @GSerg That is for java, this is c.

Comment: @RedX I searched for a duplicate and didn't notice it was for Java because the underlying reason is the same.

Comment: @Gserg Java does not have unsigned types only signed. This might add to the confusion.

Comment: And behavior like this is why an implementation might define `INT_MIN` int `limits.h` as `(-2147483647-1)`.

Comment: You really should use `%zu` (C99) to print the value of `sizeof` operator (or convert to int): `printf("%zu\n", sizeof 42);` or `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof 42);`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The rules of integer constant in C is that an decimal integer constant has the first type in which it can be represented to in: `int`, `long`, `long long`.

```
2147483648
```

does not fit into an `int` into your system (as the maximum `int` in your system is `2147483647`) so its type is a `long` (or a `long long` depending on your system). So you are computing `sizeof (long)` (or `sizeof (long long)` depending on your system).

```
2147483647
```

is an `int` in your system and if you add `1` to an `int` it is still an `int`. So you are computing `sizeof (int)`.

<s>Note that `sizeof(2147483647+1)` invokes undefined behavior in your system as `INT_MAX + 1` overflows and signed integer overflows is undefined behavior in C.</s>

Note that while generally `2147483647+1` invokes undefined behavior in your system (`INT_MAX + 1` overflows and signed integer overflows is undefined behavior in C), `sizeof(2147483647+1)` does not invoke undefined behavior as the operand of `sizeof` in this case is not evaluated.

Comment: Are you sure there is undefined behavior here, given that the expression appears as an argument to `sizeof` rather than in a context where it would be evaluated?

Comment: I suspect that it will invoke UB. `2147483647+1` will not be evaluated.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Does not evaluating the expression to which sizeof is applied make it legal to dereference a null or invalid pointer inside sizeof in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28714018/11683).

Comment: I think it does not invoke UB for the same reason that `sizeof *ptr` doesn't. The type will be `int` according to integer promotion rules

Comment: As a sidenote: `sizeof(1/0)` also produces the same as `sizeof(int)`